# ConEmu + bash script commands?

Tags: bash, git, conemu

I am writing a bash script to loop through multiple repositories and open a tab for each one inside of a single ConEmu window.

```
/c/Users/me/Desktop/ConEmu\ Container/ConEmu64.exe -reuse -run "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\bin\bash.exe" -new_console:t:$DIRECTORY -new_console:d:"${winPath}" &
```

Now this line of code works, it creates the correct tabs, but **I want to add onto this command so it runs "git pull"** in that particular tab when it opens. I want this so I can look through the status of all my repos. I have tried reading documentation, but I cannot seem to convey my goal in search-engine friendly words.

Can anyone help me add a git command to this code?

Comment: Do you need opened shell in tabs or not?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved; the following does a few commands on tab start-up and then becomes interactive. Cheers!

/c/Users/me/Desktop/ConEmu\ Container/ConEmu64.exe -reuse -run "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\bin\bash.exe  **--login -c ls && pwd && 'git pull' && bash --login -i**" -new_console:t:$DIRECTORY -new_console:d:"${winPath}" &